# Modifying JQ filter to yield comma-delimited key-value pairs

Tags: linux, bash, jq

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
js="{\"fizz\":\"buzz\",\"foo\":\"baz\"}"
echo $js

json=$(echo "$js" | jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\")|.[]")

echo "fetching secret json:"
echo $json
```

When I run it I get this:

```
myuser@mymachine myapp % bash myscript.sh
{"fizz":"buzz","foo":"baz"}
fetching secret json:
fizz=buzz foo=baz
```

In reality the JSON will be a **lot** larger than just 2 properties, but it *will* be a flat mapping of key-value pairs (no object nesting).

I actually need these map entries in comma-delimited key-value pairs. So instead of:

```
fizz=buzz foo=baz
```

I need:

```
fizz=buzz,foo=baz
```

What can I do to my `jq` filters (or elsewhere) to get a comma inserted in between the key-value pairs? To be clear I'm **not** looking for valid JSON output, nor CSV format. I need comma-delimited KV pairs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use outer single quotes, so you don't have to escape all the inner quotes: `js='{"fizz":"buzz","foo":"baz"}'` -- particularly important for quoting code passed to other interpreters like awk or jq where `$var` is a jq variable not a shell variable.

Comment: Of course the "comma-delimited KV pairs" format becomes problematic if the keys or the values have (or might have) commas. Anyone concerned about such a possibility might wish to consider `@csv` or (perhaps even better) `@tsv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [join](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#join(str)) them.

```
jq -r 'to_entries | map("\(.key)=\(.value)") | join(",")'
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/NjML_ilj62E)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, another take:

```bash
jq -r '
    def values: . as $obj | keys | map($obj[.]);
    def pairs: [keys, values] | transpose;
    pairs | map(join("=")) | join(",")
'
```